# Union 3 tables with specific column

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables and I want to union all but only two columns are able to show data.

```
SELECT Vehicle_ID, Total_Weight, date, bilty_No FROM harvesting
UNION
SELECT Vehicle_ID, Total_Weight, date, Bilty_No FROM Blade_Harvesting
```

I want to add another table like below but its giving error

```
SELECT Vehicle_ID, Total_Weight, date, bilty_No FROM harvesting
UNION
SELECT Vehicle_ID, Total_Weight, date, Bilty_No FROM Blade_Harvesting
UNION
SELECT Vehicle_ID, Vehicle_Name FROM Vehicle
```

It's giving this error:

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists

Comment: In your third select statement for Vehicle table, you must select four columns having similar data types to above two tables' column number 3 and 4

Comment: In most databases, the number _and_ types of columns in all parts of a `UNION` query have to be the same.  So if you are selecting number, number, date, number, then all queries in the `UNION` have to follow suit.

Comment: Please send query...i'm new one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please user :

SELECT Vehicle_ID, Total_Weight,     date,   Bilty_No, '' AS Vehicle_Name   FROM harvesting

UNION 
SELECT Vehicle_ID, Total_Weight,      date,  Bilty_No, '' AS Vehicle_Name  FROM Blade_Harvesting

UNION 
SELECT Vehicle_ID, '0' AS Total_Weight, NULL AS date, '0' AS Bilty_No,  Vehicle_Name FROM Vehicle

Comment: i want to show vehicle_name instead of vehicle_ID on all rows

Answer (score 3):

You must specify equal columns in your all UNION SELECT clause :

```
   SELECT Vehicle_ID VehicleId, Total_Weight TotalWeight,date,bilty_No 
          biltyNo,'' VehicleName
   FROM harvesting 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Vehicle_ID VehicleId, Total_Weight TotalWeight,date,Bilty_No 
          biltyNo ,'' VehicleName
   FROM Blade_Harvesting 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Vehicle_ID VehicleId ,0 TotalWeight,'' date ,'' biltyNo 
          ,Vehicle_Name VehicleName
   FROM Vehicle
```

Comment: Why not NULL instead?

Comment: I have a little bit problem, query runs very well but when i check data its showing 6 rows with data but when i check my actual database it should be show 4 rows.. Like i have 3 rows in harvesting table and 1 row in blade_harvesting table so result should be show 4 rows... please help

Comment: @MohammadImran,Specify your 3 + 1 table datas.

Comment: i have 3 tables..1 harvesting 2nd blade_harvesting and 3rd vehicle..3 records in harvesting table and 1 is in blade_harvesting table and i want to show vehicle_name instead of vehicle_ID

Answer (score 0):

Each SELECT statement within `UNION` must have the same number of columns.
The columns must also have similar data types.
The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order

Try this

```
SELECT Vehicle_ID,cast(Total_Weight as varchar),date,bilty_No FROM harvesting
UNION
SELECT Vehicle_ID,cast(Total_Weight as varchar),date,Bilty_No FROM Blade_Harvesting
union
select Vehicle_ID,Vehicle_Name,'','' from Vehicle
```

Comment: its giving error .q..Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'TX-001' to data type int.

Comment: that is because your `Total_Weight` column is of datatype `INT` whereas `Vehicle_Name` is a `Varchar` field,cast your `Total_Weight` to varchar. I have edited the answer

Comment: I have a little bit problem, query runs very well but when i check data its showing 6 rows with data but when i check my actual database it should be show 4 rows.. Like i have 3 rows in harvesting table and 1 row in blade_harvesting table so result should be show 4 rows.